# is save() necessary when commit() is used?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I realized that `save()` and `commit()` will perform the same database transaction twice.

Eg.

```
if (isset($userId)) 
{
    $update = true;
    $user->load(array('id=:id', array(':id' => $userId)));
}

$user->designation_id = $f3->get('POST.designation_id');
$user->firstname = $f3->get('POST.firstname');
$user->lastname = $f3->get('POST.lastname');

$user->save(); //update made to users table

$this->db->begin();

foreach ($userTeams as $teamId) 
{
     $sqlArray[] = sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (internal_team_id, users_id) VALUES (%d,%d)', 'users_internal_team', $teamId, $user->get('_id'));
}
$this->db->exec($sqlArray); //update made to some other table

$this->db->commit();

echo $this->db->log();
die();
```

The log will show me the following transactions executed in `"users"` table:

```
...other log information related to other tables..

UPDATE `users` SET `designation_id`=3,`lastname`='Mali' WHERE `id`=134 Wed, 11 Apr 2018 11:39:20 +0200 (0.5ms) 
UPDATE `users` SET `designation_id`=3,`lastname`='Mali' WHERE `id`=134
```

So does this mean that I can remove `$user->save()` and `$this->db->commit()` will do the same for me?

Comment: `commit()` can only be used in SQL. Since the DB Mapper works for other engines too there's a `save()` method.

Comment: No, you must save the data. The commit just applies a set of `save()`'s done between a BeginTransaction and EndTransaction or if something goes wrong between a Begin and End those chnages are all rolledback

Comment: I *assume* that save acts on the database table, whereas commits marks the transaction to be completed. Meaning once you rollback, your database looks like as the transaction never happened. So they are not doing the same, one saves into the table, the other finalizes on success.

Comment: But when I remove user->save() part, it is working fine too and only one Update transaction is being executed.
While with the user->save() and commit() both, two update transactions are being executed.

Comment: Its not really clear whats going on in this code. But I suggest you readup on the Transaction concept in the manual

Comment: Well actually you only `save` the `$user` apparently Outside the transaction, then you go and do some Raw SQL INSERTS, within a transaction. Without knowing what goes on before thsi code is run its difficult to know what you are actually doing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

`save()` and `commit()` are two different things, so you shouldn't skip `save()`.

### SQL background

In SQL, you can write:

```
UPDATE users SET designation_id=3,lastname='Mali' WHERE id=134;
INSERT INTO users_internal_team (internal_team_id, users_id) VALUES;(999,134)
```

Or you can write:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE users SET designation_id=3,lastname='Mali' WHERE id=134;
INSERT INTO users_internal_team (internal_team_id, users_id) VALUES;(999,134)
COMMIT;
```

The difference being that, in the first example, if an error occured during the `INSERT` statement (like a duplicate entry), the `UPDATE` statement wouldn't be cancelled (aka "rolled back"), while in the second example it would.

In F3, the equivalent examples would be:

```
$db->exec('UPDATE users etc.');
$db->exec('INSERT INTO users_internal_team etc.');
```

and

```
$db->begin();
$db->exec('UPDATE users etc.');
$db->exec('INSERT INTO users_internal_team etc.');
$db->commit();
```

Note that, if you pass an array of statements to the `exec()` method, they will automatically be embedded inside a transaction:

```
$db->exec([
  'UPDATE users etc.',
  'INSERT INTO users_internal_team etc.',
]);
// automatically calls $db->begin() and $db->commit()
```

### Your code

In your code, you're calling `user->save()`, which triggers either a `$db->exec('INSERT etc.')` or a `$db->exec('UPDATE etc.')`, depending on the result of the preceding `$user->load()`.

That's one statement.

The fact that two identical statements appear in the log and that one of them still shows up when you skip the call to `$user->save()` let me think that `$sqlArray` must be containing that same statement.

I may be wrong on the latter point, but in any case, the sequence you're using is correct.

Comment: `$sqlArray` don't have that statement.. I checked it and re-checked it.. Don't know what is causing this.. But `commit()` alone seems to have done the job of `save()`.. removing `save()` is giving the result as expected.

Comment: That's really strange. I just made a test case but couldn't reproduce your issue. Are you using an old release? Also you should make sure that the query is actually executed twice. It could be executed once and logged twice. BTW, I updated the answer to notify that when you pass an array of statements to `exec()`, `$db->begin()` and `$db->commit()` are automatically executed.

Comment: I have defined a trigger on update/insert for that table, and that is how I discovered that the statement is executed twice.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. Really appreciated it.